# Suddenly i cant put mask on anything

Tags: sculpting, masking

this happens to me suddenly after i try to mask something in this case i was trying to create a bear and i sculped the nose but when it came to the mouth it stopped working

i tried recreating the project and the mask tool worked i did the eyes mouth but i cant do the nose i repeated the procses alot and i cant seem to find the problem here is the photo and a video i tried to mask the nose but then it stopped so i CNTRL+Z to see if i undo the nose mask and make it flat again would the tool work but it wouldnt Please someone help[image]

Comment: i forgot to remove the video part i copied my post from reddit so my video isnt here sorry here is the video on the reddit post https://www.reddit.com/r/blenderhelp/comments/13i5foj/suddenly_i_cant_put_mask_on_anything/

Comment: Hello could you please share your object? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=PbQLwSQj" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/PbQLwSQj/)

Comment: I try and it seems to work fine, I can create a mask on the nose, there's already a mask on the nose by the way

Comment: @moonboots can u check the video i sent on reddit it isnt masking for me

Comment: Yes that's weird, see what I see when I open your file: https://zupimages.net/up/23/20/708a.jpg ... have you tried another Blender version?

Comment: Oh ok it may be invisible, try Ctrl M, I don't know why Ctrl M doesn't exist in the latest version

Comment: @moonboots Holy potatos ur right thank u :D (im not even using blender im using upbge so im probably not on the latest version

Answer (score 0):

Your mask is... masked, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> to make it visible again. It was visible for me in 3.5.1 because for some reason the function is not available in this version.